# Find Maximum Date from the List Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am try to automate one task in my Excel but at one point i am stuck and i am not able to crack it.
SO here in below image as you can see i have order order number and have multiple dates in it. so how can i find maximum date for that particular order and go to next order number and repeat the same step can anyone help me to crack it.

[image]

Comment: is the image above from a pivot table or you created a manual grouping?

Comment: If it's a pivot table drag your date from the row to the "value" section > choose "value field setting" > Summarize by max. You'll probably need to reset the format to date.